# Automatic script execution in order to save objects into Global Environment using batch files and/or windows task scheduler

Tags: r

I'm not an R expert and I'm not very good at english language, so keep that in mind when you'll respond to my question.

I'm trying to automate some R script execution. My ultimate goal is to automate the execution of a script that can query some data from Binance exchange API, export those data into an external .csv file (or update the file with new observations if it already exists) and then import the file into RStudio Global Environment, so that I always have up to date data ready to be analyzed.

Searching on the web I learned that I can automate tasks using Windows Task Scheduler, so I downloaded [taskscheduleR package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/taskscheduleR/vignettes/taskscheduleR.html) to speed up the process. It worked quite well in fact, however I only managed to automate 2 of the 3 tasks I mentioned above:

1. Query from API
2. Export data into .csv

So, using task scheduler I can periodically query the web and export data/update existing datasets. However, I'm struggling with the 3rd task. I can't figure out how to automatically and periodically import the data into RStudio Global Environment.

In order to simplify my question I'll use a very basic code line as an example. Imagine I want to automate a script named "rnorm.R"

```
x <- rnorm(10)
```

I want the output of rnorm() to be stored into x and then loaded into the Global Environment, and I want this code line to be run every 2 minutes, so that the x values also change every 2 minutes while I'm working with Rstudio. I tried many times with different methods.

First I tried with taskscheduleR package. Used the following code:

```
require(taskscheduleR)
require(lubridate)
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "rnorm", rscript = "mydir/rnorm.R", starttime = format(ceiling_date(Sys.time(), unit = "mins"), "%H:%M), schedule = "MINUTE", modifier = 2)
```

Then, I tried with manual schedulation using Windows task scheduler.

Lastly, I tried scheduling a batch file:

```
@echo off
Rscript.exe mydir/rnorm.R
```

None of the 3 methods worked. Or better, the schedulation works, I see a command line window appear each time Windows task scheduler executes the script. However, it does nothing. The x variable isn't loaded into the Global Environment. What am I doing wrong? I'm sure this problem has a very simple and stupid answer, however I can't figure out what it may be. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: See some ideas here: https://yihui.org/en/2017/10/later-recursion/ which recommends the [later](https://cran.r-project.org/package=later) package.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for your answer. This package is quite interesting. However I can't still solve my problem. The `later::later()` method seems to work only to schedule tasks that print something on the console. For example the `print_time()` function described in [link](https://yihui.org/en/2017/10/later-recursion/) works as expected and prints the timestamp every 10 seconds on console. However if I try to save the `print_time()` outputs (for example `x <- print_time()`) it saves x as a function object `function () { invisible(cancel(id, loop_id)) }` and keeps printing timestamps on console.